# How to initialize a 2D Boolean Array with all elements False?

Tags: java

The title describes the question. Here's the code:

```
boolean planeArray[][];
```

Answer (score 14):

Just with

```
boolean planeArray[][] = new boolean[rows][columns];
```

all values will be **`false` by default**.

---

You can also initialize with the number of rows:

```
boolean planeArray[][] = new boolean[rows][];
```

and then assign each row an 1D-array:

```
planeArray[0] = new boolean[columns];
...
```

Note that by using this last way, rows can have different number of columns.

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize the array and the default value of `boolean` will be set to all the indexs element which is `false`.

```
boolean planeArray[][]  =  new boolean[row_size][column_size];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like the following.

Assuming its a 2x2 array.

```
boolean[][] planeArray = new boolean[][]{{true, true},
                                         {true, false}
                                         };
```

Or if its a 3x3 array, you can just add the elements you need.

```
boolean[][] planeArray = new boolean[][]{{true, true, true},
                                         {true, true, true},
                                         {true, true, true}
                                        };
```

and so you basically add more elements to rows or cols depending on the size of the 2d you want.

Answer (score 0):

**grid = new boolean[n][n];**

Simply typing the above line of code would result in the creation of a (n x n) 2-D array with default values set to false.

However, the complexity remains O(n^2) with or without the usage of 2 loops(nested).
It would only reduce the number of lines of code, redundant code.

Answer (score -1):

A boolean is by default false however the array which you make hasn't been initialized yetso you would need a nested for loops for each dimension of the array as in the following code:

```
boolean bool[][] = new bool[10][10];

for(int a = 0; a < bool.length; a++){
    for(int b = 0; b < bool[a].length; b++){
        bool[a][b] = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Default values for `boolean` makes them all false, so the loops are redundant.

Comment: This is true if Boolean is Object & is not of primitive type (boolean)